# What is the limit of the serie $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^4}{(1+x^2)^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the series :

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^4}{(1+x^2)^k}$$

So, I applied the ratio test and did $\frac{x^4}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$*$\frac{(1+x^2)^n}{x^4}$.

Then, I get $1 + \frac{1}{x^2}$. I then multiply $1 + \frac{1}{x^2}$ by $x^4$, to which I get an answer choice of (E) $x^4 + x^2$

I kind of want to know if I'm actually doing the process correctly, and that $x^4 + x^2$ is the limit of the aforementioned series.

These are the following answer choices:

(A) $x^6 + x^4$
(B) $\frac{x^6}{1+x^2}$
(C) $x^6$
(D) $x^4$ + $\frac{x^6}{1+x^2}$
(E) $x^4$ + $x^2$

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you finding the limit as $n$ tends to infinity? Also, if your question is multiple-choice, what are the choices?

Comment: That is the question. It's from some gre subject test. I'll try to edit and put in the answer choices as well soon.

Comment: Is this what you meant , Sharon ?

Comment: Yes, it's an easier way of writing the question. I'm sure it would be helpful to others. I just wrote it exactly the way it was written from the source.

Comment: It’s a finite geometric series notice the x^4 not depend on index. Ratio test for infinite series to determine convergence

Comment: I edited again. It's supposed to be infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint:** You basically have a geometric series with the first term $a_1 = x^4, r = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. The sum is $\dfrac{a_1}{1-r}=...$

Comment: that's a much easier method. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is $x^4(\sum_{n\geq 0}({1\over{1+x^2}})^n=x^4({1\over{1-{1\over{1+x^2}}}})$